# How to reset a cooldown of the SlashCommand in dsharp+ on error

Tags: c#, dsharp+

I'm making hazard/fantasy discord bot for friends and as a project for school.
So I got blocked by cooldowns. Currently if player uses /blackjack with amount lower than user have it displays appropriate error but still giving cooldown for that user. I tried to find answer in C# but there ain't any. I just don't get how cooldowns are stored on Discord or how could I make my own attribute to save on local database. Hope to get some directions :D

```cs
    [SlashCommand("blackjack", "Play a game of blackjack!")]
    [SlashCooldown(1, 60 * 5, SlashCooldownBucketType.User)]
    public async Task Blackjack(InteractionContext ctx, 
        [Option("amount", "Amount to bet (Minimum 50$)")] double amountGiven)
    {
        await ctx.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.DeferredChannelMessageWithSource);

        var userProfile = await _playerService.GetOrCreatePlayerAsync(ctx.Member.Id);

        var amount = (int)amountGiven;

        DiscordEmbedBuilder? moneyErrorMessage = null;
        
        if(amount < MINIMUM_MONEY_REQ)
        {
            moneyErrorMessage = new DiscordEmbedBuilder()
                .WithDescription("You need atleast 50$ to play blackjack!")
                .WithColor(DiscordColor.Red);
        }
        else if(amount > userProfile.Balance)
        {
            moneyErrorMessage = new DiscordEmbedBuilder()
                .WithDescription($"You wanted to bet {amount}$ but you have only {userProfile.Balance}$")
                .WithColor(DiscordColor.Red);
        }

        if (moneyErrorMessage != null)
        {
            await ctx.EditResponseAsync(new DiscordWebhookBuilder().AddEmbed(moneyErrorMessage));

            // TODO: Some way to reset the cooldown of that command
            return;
        }
    }
```

For now I display message on error that get the cooldown values, but I can't do anything with that.

```cs
    private async Task OnErrorOccured(SlashCommandsExtension sender, SlashCommandErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        await e.Context.CreateResponseAsync(InteractionResponseType.DeferredChannelMessageWithSource);

        var errorEmbed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder()
            .WithColor(DiscordColor.Red);

        if(e.Exception is SlashExecutionChecksFailedException)
        {
            var castedException = (SlashExecutionChecksFailedException)e.Exception;
            var timeLeft = String.Empty;
            foreach (var error in castedException.FailedChecks)
            {
                var cooldown = (SlashCooldownAttribute)error;
                TimeSpan rawTime = cooldown.GetRemainingCooldown(e.Context);

                if (rawTime.Days != 0) timeLeft += $"{rawTime.Days} days, ";
                if (rawTime.Hours != 0) timeLeft += $"{rawTime.Hours} hours, ";
                if (rawTime.Minutes!= 0) timeLeft += $"{rawTime.Minutes} minutes, ";
                if (rawTime.Seconds != 0) timeLeft += $"{rawTime.Seconds} seconds";
            }

            errorEmbed
                .WithTitle("**HOLD UP!**")
                .WithDescription($"To use that command you need to wait {timeLeft}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can tell cooldowns only have read-only properties. Your best bet may be to abstract the actual blackjack work into another method with its own cooldown and then only call that method after checking against your guard clauses. I think this should work still if you pass your ctx to the new method.

Comment: Just to add to that, you can make the new method that does all of the actual blackjack work hidden by adding the attribute `[Hidden]` to it.